# Need help finding an old game I want to rewrite/port

Tags: porting

There was this old stick figure game for Windows I played a while back. You, playing as a stick figure, run around on a 2d map with guns and fight other stick figures. You can get power ups, like jetpacks, bigger guns and the like.

It's a very simple game with not much to it. I think it came with a map editor as well.

Google results only provide me with subpar flash games and some Stick War game that clearly isn't it.

I want to write a Linux port and I would like to give it another run before I start that process.

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Probably a better question for [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/?as=1). Since it's not actually about game development.

Comment: I asked the question over at Arqade. Not sure if there is a way to delete this question here or move it to another stack exchange entirely. Thanks @Byte56

Comment: @Byte56 they don't accept identify questions anymore... in fact they've deleted em all (losing some good damn answers in the process)

Comment: Is your game here? http://www.stickpage.com/

Comment: Ah, bummer. I guess it makes sense. Unfortunately I think it's more off topic here than there :/. We'll try to get you some rep over there so you can get into chat :)

Comment: @Kyle Well, I tried. You can try answering some questions over there, that'll get you enough rep pretty fast.